# Sending email with codeigniter (newbie)

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, gmail

I am a noob in Codeigniter and i want to make a contact form and i want that to send to my gmail. I made a view:

```
<div id="content">
<?php if (isset($mail_sent)): ?>
<b>Mail Sent</b>
<?php endif; ?>

<form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>" method="POST">

<b>Your Name :</b>
<br />
<input type="text" name="name" />
<br />
<b>Your Email Address:</b>
<br />
<input type="text" name="from" />
<br />
<b>Subject :</b>
<br />
<input type="text" name="subject" />
<br />
<b>Message :</b>
<br />
<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="15"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="q" value="Contact" />

</form>
</div>
```

i have the mail settings in the same controller codeblock tahn my contact page. it looks like this:

```
public function contact()
{
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('owrb_contact');
    $this->load->view('footer');

    $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
    $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';

    // gmail specific settings here
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'keessonnema@gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '123keesje123';
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';

    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('keessonnema@gmail.com', 'Kees Sonnema');

    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

    $this->email->send();
}
```

Now i have to configure a smtp gmail controller? i really have no idea of how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: it looks like the posts but i don't get the logic yet. so they can post a lot of code but i need a clean and easy to read tutorial or something for sending email with CI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send mail with the Codeigniter Framework, it's described here.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html

There's settings for protocol, servers and every item you could ever wish to configurate. You can hook this up with gmail if you want as well.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';

// gmail specific settings here
$config['smtp_host'] = '';
$config['smtp_user'] = '';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '';
$config['smtp_port'] = '';

$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

$this->email->send();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it's all a little strange because it's new for me, but the problem is that there isn't a good tutorial on how to do this. but i will try this.

Comment: I think if you combine the Controller guide with the documentation for how to send a mail, you should be able to create a mail controller. They're not a complete guide I'm afraid but they provide the information you need. Here the url to the Controller guide.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

Comment: hm it's really tricky i can't figure out somehow. maybe you can post a little example? do i have to put the mail settings in my default controller or do i have to make a new one?

Comment: It all depends on where you want to post your html form. You can post it to your default controller and just check if the mail form in question is posted, and do your magic there. :) Or you can simply create a new Controller and point the form action there. It's totally up to you how you want to design your controller logic. That's the beauty of it.

Comment: allright :) i hope i learn fast about this things because now it goes really slowly